# Custom search filter is not showing any result

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom search filter to show events by states and customized the code, but it in showing any results when a state is selected. Here is the code:

```
    add_filter( 'event_manager_get_listings', 'filter_by_state_field_query_args', 10, 2 );
function filter_by_state_field_query_args( $query_args, $args ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['form_data'] ) ) {
        parse_str( $_POST['form_data'], $form_data );
        // If this is set, we are filtering by state
        if ( ! empty( $form_data['filter_by_state'] ) ) {
            $event_state = sanitize_text_field( $form_data['filter_by_state'] );
            $query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
                        'key'     => '_event_state',
                        'value'   => $event_state,
                        );
        }
    }
    return $query_args;
}
```

Comment: Is your meta key name really `_event_state`, or should that maybe be just `event_state`?

Comment: I tried changing the meta key to just _state and it is working. Thanks